# Jasper 7.1 displayes garbled home page

Tags: jasperserver

We used Apache tomcat 8.5.27 and deployed Jasper reports server 7.1.  The deployment was successful with no issues and when we access the homepage, it displays the garbled home page and does not load. However, on deploying jasper reports server 6.2 login page works fine and loads all images etc in perfect manner. Please advice of there is anything to be done.

The jasper reports 7.1 is a WAR file. [Garbled login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19MsK.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

When we upgade from 6.x version to 7 version, There is a file in WEB-INF/application-context.themes.xml. This will have two options to load Themes from file or DB.

7.1 was using loading from DB and faiing.

## we reconfigured the application-context-themes.xml and that fixed the problem.